# How to use orderby inside relation on laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, model, sql-order-by

i know this is funny question but i cannot solve it using relation.

Here are my model :

```
public function category(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Master\Product\Category');
}
```

Here are my controller:

```
$products = Product::with('category')->orderBy('category.name')->get();
```

But i get error Unknown error column 'category.name', although the column exist. I know i can solve this using leftjoin like this :

```
$products= Product::leftJoin('categories', 'categories.id','products.category_id')->orderBy('categories.name')->get();
```

But how about if i want only using OrderBy inside that relation?

Comment: *But i get error Unknown error column 'category.name', although the column exist.* Do not tell a tale about the error, provide complete error message text.

Comment: try ```$products= Product::leftJoin('categories', 'categories.id','products.category_id')->orderBy('name')->get();```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$products = Product::with(['category' => fn($q) => $q->orderBy('name')])->get();
```

See [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) in documentation to get more details

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$products = Product::with(['category' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('name');
}])->orderBy('category_id')->get();
```